# Filter on arrays on Objects inside array of Objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, filter

I would like to get an array of the Main by category

```js
[
  {
    "@id": "/api/main/7648",
    "@type": "Main",
    category: [{
      name: "laboriosam"
    }]
  },
  {
    "@id": "/api/main/7647",
    "@type": "Main",
    category: [{
        name: "foo"
      },
      {
        name: "bar"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So I try:

```js
console.log([...this.state.mains].filter(main => main.category.filter(category => category.name == "foo")))
```

But it returns me everything and I don't understand why?

Comment: What do you mean with an array of the Main? An array of "Main" strings or the objects which have a "@type" = "Main"?

Comment: I mean an array of the object with "@type": "Main"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Array.prototype.some`, you can decide if the value is existed or not.

Using `Array.filter` function, it filters the `true` values only so it is needed to return boolean value on callback.

```js
const input = [{
    "@id": "/api/main/7648",
    "@type": "Main",
    category: [{
      name: "laboriosam"
    }]
  },
  {
    "@id": "/api/main/7647",
    "@type": "Main",
    category: [{
        name: "foo"
      },
      {
        name: "bar"
      }
    ]
  }
];

console.log(input.filter(main => main.category.some(category => category.name == "foo")))
```

Answer (score 0):

I find your question really hard to understand. If you want just the objects with @type = "Main" you can do

```
this.state.mains.filter(x => x["@type"] === "Main");
```

If you then want to filter those out who don't have a certain category you can add another filter like so:

```
this.state.mains
   .filter(x => x["@type"] === "Main")
   .filter(x => x.category.findIndex(c => c.name === "foo") !== -1);
```

Obviously in case of big array you also put both checks into one filter, but that might not be as readable.

Also note that `[...this.state.mains].filter(...)` is redundant, as `.filter()` already returns a new array.